# Unable to click button with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am having trouble clicking the login button with Selenium. Here's my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")


driver.get('https://myfit4less.gymmanager.com/portal/login.asp')
driver.find_element_by_id("loginButton").click()
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <div id="loginButton" class="button">...</div> is not clickable at point (236, 589). Other element would receive the click: <div class="footer">...</div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you had was an overlaying element you could just target the element to click instead.

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_id("loginButton")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elem)
```